# Compared lists in google apps script

Tags: list, google-apps-script, comparison

I am trying to compare 2 lists and find elements in list1 that are NOT present in list2.

```
list1: [01-0161051, 01-0161053, 01-0161057, 01-0161058, 01-0161065, 01-0161067, 01-0161068]
list2: [01-0161051, 01-0161053, 01-0161057, 01-0161058, 01-0161065, 01-0161066]
```

Elements in list1 but not in list2 are [01-0161067, 01-0161068]

I tried this code but it does not yield expected results:

```
missing = null,
i = list1.length;
while(i) {
missing = ( ~list1.indexOf(list2[--i]) ) ? missing : list1[i];
}
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var list1 = ['01-0161051', '01-0161053', '01-0161057', '01-0161058', '01-0161065', '01-0161067', '01-0161068'];
var list2 = ['01-0161051', '01-0161053', '01-0161057', '01-0161058', '01-0161065', '01-0161066'];

var missing = list1.filter(x => !list2.includes(x));

console.log(missing); // [ '01-0161067', '01-0161068' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function findInOneNotInTwo() {
  const list1 = ['01-0161051', '01-0161053', '01-0161057', '01-0161058', '01-0161065', '01-0161067', '01-0161068'];
  const list2 = ['01-0161051', '01-0161053', '01-0161057', '01-0161058', '01-0161065', '01-0161066'];
  let in1notin2 = [];
  list1.forEach(s=>{
    if(!~list2.indexOf(s)) {
      in1notin2.push(s);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(in1notin2.join(', '));
}

Execution log
1:54:09 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:54:11 PM  Info    01-0161067, 01-0161068
1:54:10 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```